# Mapping a Json object depending on a value from another mapping

Tags: reactjs

I have two calls from different api's.
What i want to achieve is an async loading of the status value.
I'am trying to achieve a mapping that depends from a value that comes from another mapping.
I list some machine names from one mapping and then i want do another mapping that lists a status value for each of this machines:

```
Machine1 On
Machine2 Off
```

The code bellow only shows the two mappings that i am making, this already prints a list but the status value first displays all ON then all OFF, and i want that each machine gets it's own status value.

```
return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <h1>Azure machines</h1>
      <Table className={classes.table} size="small">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="left">name</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">resource_group</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">location</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">status</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {data.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.name + row.resource_group}>
              <TableCell align="left" component="th" scope="row">
                <StyledButton size = "small" className={style.size3}>
                     <Link  style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'inherit'}} to={`/machines/${row.resource_group + "/" + row.name}`}>{row.name}</Link>
                  </StyledButton>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">{row.resource_group}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">{row.location}</TableCell>
            {MachinesRow.map(key => (
               <TableCell  key= {key.location + key.name}align="left">
                 <MachineStatusIcon
                  status_code={key.status_code}
                  status={key.status}
            />
               </TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
         ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>

    </div>
  )
}
```

I was trying something like this, but it didn't work:

```
               {foreach(row.machine) => {
               {MachinesRow.map(key => (
               <TableCell  key= {key.location + key.name}align="left">
                 <MachineStatusIcon
                  status_code={key.status_code}
                  status={key.status}
            />
               </TableCell>
            ))} }
```

Data Json that has the Machine name on it:

```
{
name: "test"
location: "europe"
resource_group: "group1"
}
```

MachineRow Json that has the status:

```
{
name: "test"
status: "VM running"
status_code: "PowerState/running"
}
```

Comment: Could you show us what those JSON look like ?

Comment: updated the question, thanks

Comment: So `data` contains the first JSON and `MachinesRow` contains the second one ?

Comment: yes Scalpweb, i forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is merging those 2 objets (data and MachinesRow) together, based on the `name` property. You could do something like this:

```
const merged = {};
data.forEach(d => merged[d.name] = {...d});
MachinesRow.forEach(d => merged[d.name] = {...(merged[d.name] || {}), ...d});
```

Then you have an array `merged` that contains a merge of those 2 objects, and you can do:

```
{merged.map(row => (
  <TableRow key={row.name + row.resource_group}>
    <TableCell align="left" component="th" scope="row">
      <StyledButton size = "small" className={style.size3}>
           <Link  style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'inherit'}} to={`/machines/${row.resource_group + "/" + row.name}`}>{row.name}</Link>
        </StyledButton>
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{row.resource_group}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{row.location}</TableCell>
     <TableCell  key= {row.location + row.name}align="left">
       <MachineStatusIcon
        status_code={row.status_code}
        status={row.status}
     </TableCell>
  </TableRow>
))}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is that i want to load each status async, so it does not take ages loading the page, and with that i would load all at the same time

Comment: Ah my bad. Then you should create another component to display the status. You pass it the name of the machine as props, and you do the fetch request inside this new component.